# Samsung Galaxy S2 factory-reset lead to boot-loop

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, factory-reset, boot-loop

I have a *Samsung Galaxy S2*. I factory-reset my phone from the *Settings* option, but it is taking too much time. It has been 24 hours already, but the device is only boot-looping. I've also tried to boot into recovery-mode (by holding the <kbd>Vol+</kbd> and <kbd>Vol-</kbd> buttons while pressing <kbd>Power</kbd>), but this boot-looped as well.

How can I solve this problem? The device is rooted, if that's any help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126507/discussion-on-question-by-elham-samsung-galaxy-s2-factory-reset-lead-to-boot-loo).

Answer (score 1):

Get a USB jig, that will get you into download mode. It's just a 300k Ohm resistor that bridges a couple of pins on the USB port.

Answer (score 1):

I have Samsung phones that have this bug in which you go to boot-loop in almost every reboot session. I also faced this, so I luckily have a solution and see if it works.

Just turn off the phone completely, remove the battery, wait for a minute or two, put the battery back in, and start the phone. This started my phone correctly as it was previously stuck on the black bootloader screen and wasn't even going to the boot animation stage.